# Groovy: escape lower level JSON

Tags: json, groovy

I need to keep the first level JSON keys and convert the values to escaped strings, but only in case the values are also JSON objects. How can this be done in Groovy?

Input sample:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": {
    "c": "2",
    "d": {
      "e": "3"
    }
  },
  "f": "4"
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "{ \"c\": \"2\", \"d\": { \"e\": \"3\"} }",
  "f": "4"
}
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried and how it failed so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `JsonSlurper` to parse the input JSON, then any nested JSON object will be represented as a `LazyMap`. You can use this information to collect all entries from the parsed JSON object (which is also a map) and convert any map object to its JSON string representation. You can convert any value to a JSON string representation using `groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(object)` method.

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input = '''{
  "a": "1",
  "b": {
    "c": "2",
    "d": {
      "e": "3"
    }
  },
  "f": "4"
}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)

def escaped = json.collectEntries { k,v ->
    [(k): v instanceof Map ? new JsonOutput().toJson(v) : v]
}

def output = new JsonOutput().prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(escaped))

println output
```

Output:

```
{
    "a": "1",
    "b": "{\"c\":\"2\",\"d\":{\"e\":\"3\"}}",
    "f": "4"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, t's the `escaped` line that does the trick that I need.